# how to delete a key from object which has value as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I have a javascript object which has a large amount of key value pairs in it, among them some of the keys have a value as undefined. I what to delete the keys which have the value as undefined.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

With underscore you can use the [**filter**](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) function:

```
var data = { a: 1, b: undefined, c: 3};

var noUndefineds = _.filter(data, function(value){
    return value != undefined;
});
```

or use the [**reject**](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) function with the isUndefined predicate:

```
var noUndefineds = _.reject(data, _.isUndefined);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like below:

```
for(var k in obj) { 
  if (typeof obj[k] == 'undefined') { 
    delete obj[k]; 
}}
```